# GWT formpanel works for chrome but does not work for firefox

Tags: java, firefox, gwt, servlets

This code works in chrome. But in firefox, it does not call the servlet. Below is the code. I do not know whether it is a browser difference.

```
     String URL= GWT.getModuleBaseURL()+"getType";
     FormPanel formPanel = new FormPanel();  
     formPanel.setAction(URL); 
     formPanel.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_URLENCODED);  
     formPanel.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_GET); 

 formPanel.addSubmitHandler(new SubmitHandler(){

    @Override
    public void onSubmit(SubmitEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(event.getSource());
    }

 });
 formPanel.addSubmitCompleteHandler(new FormPanel.SubmitCompleteHandler() {  
        public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event) { 
            System.out.println("in");
            System.out.println(event.getResults());  
        }  
    });  
 formPanel.submit();
```

The xml file is below.

```
 web.xml
<servlet>
<servlet-name>getType</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>msp2.server.getType</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>getType</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/msp2_app/getType</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>`
```

Comment: are you adding the formpanel to the DOM?

Comment: What is DOM? I am a beginner. Thx

Comment: Where did you add your panel? (Something like RootPanel.get().add(formPanel))

Comment: I do not add this panel to RootPanel. Is it the problem? But it works in Chrome

Comment: Yes you need to add `formPanel` to `RootPanel` or to a `Widget` that is added to `RootPanel` in order to make it visible in browser.

Answer (score 3):

In order for the form to work correctly you need to add it to the DOM.

This could be done by calling:

```
RootPanel.get().add(formPanel);
```

or you can use any panel that is already attached